# jQuery UI Range Slider event conditions

Tags: jquery-ui

I need to use a Range Slider to set a time range (8-23) but I need some base conditions on it (I basically need the minimum range to be 1h):

- When the two pickers are on the same position the right piker goes "+1"
- On right limit (23) the values have to be "22,23)

Here is the code as I tested so far: [JSFiddle URL](http://jsfiddle.net/convoy83/FzGwU/)

This works only before the right limit of the slider, when I have "23,23" or "22,23" my *getSlide* check function does not work properly and I don't understand how to fix it..

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself coding all conditions only in slide event:

```
...
slide: function (event, ui) {
    val1 = ui.values[0];
    val2 = ui.values[1];
    if(val2-val1 < 1 || val1 > 22){
         return false;
    }
    $("#start").text(ui.values[0]);
    $("#stop").text(ui.values[1]);
},
...
```

The strange behaviour with the previous version is still not explained, but it works.